# keras FRCNN training error message: Exception: 'a' cannot be empty unless no samples are taken

Tags: python, keras, faster-rcnn

I am using this implementation of FRCNN for training on my dataset:

https://github.com/kbardool/keras-frcnn

during training I get random exceptions with no stack trace:

```
708/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 289s - rpn_cls: 0.1376 - rpn_regr: 0.3020 - detector_cls: 
709/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 288s - rpn_cls: 0.1376 - rpn_regr: 0.3020 - detector_cls: 
710/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 287s - rpn_cls: 0.1374 - rpn_regr: 0.3021 - detector_cls: 
711/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 286s - rpn_cls: 0.1373 - rpn_regr: 0.3018 - detector_cls: 
712/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 284s - rpn_cls: 0.1371 - rpn_regr: 0.3017 - detector_cls: 
713/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 283s - rpn_cls: 0.1370 - rpn_regr: 0.3019 - detector_cls: 
714/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 282s - rpn_cls: 0.1370 - rpn_regr: 0.3017 - detector_cls: 0.0783 - detector_regr: 0.0686
Exception: 'a' cannot be empty unless no samples are taken

715/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 281s - rpn_cls: 0.1369 - rpn_regr: 0.3015 - detector_cls: 
716/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 280s - rpn_cls: 0.1367 - rpn_regr: 0.3013 - detector_cls: 
717/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 279s - rpn_cls: 0.1365 - rpn_regr: 0.3009 - detector_cls: 
718/1000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 278s - rpn_cls: 0.1363 - rpn_regr: 0.3011 - detector_cls:
```

while I get error message, loss still goes down, what can be the reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been seeing the same error message and it doesn't seem to effect the outcome of the training session.  I have noticed when my bounding boxes on training data are < 20px this error presents itself.  Let me know if you actually determine what's causing the issue!

Comment: Looks like in ResNet50 must be greater than 64 px (min kernel of ResNet50).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a root cause and have some superficial fix, but i don't have 100% understanding of what is going on. The exception happens at second attempt to perform **np.random.choice**. If first choice fails with exception, then author is caching the exception and tries to select without deduplication. However if **neg_samples** is empty then second call produces an exception.

```
try:
    selected_neg_samples = np.random.choice(neg_samples, C.num_rois - len(selected_pos_samples), replace=False).tolist()
except:
    selected_neg_samples = np.random.choice(neg_samples, C.num_rois - len(selected_pos_samples), replace=True).tolist()
```

I have "fixed" it like this:

```
try:
  selected_neg_samples = np.random.choice(neg_samples, C.num_rois - len(selected_pos_samples), replace=False).tolist()
except:
    selected_neg_samples = np.random.choice(neg_samples, C.num_rois - len(selected_pos_samples) if len(neg_samples)>0 else 0, replace=True).tolist()
```

Again, i am not sure if its ok to sample in case neg_samples is empty. May be someone who has a better understanding of the algorithm can give reasonable comment here.